# Assigning rows evenly from table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have two tables:

```
**Users**
UserID | UserName | Password

**Task**
TaskId | Hours | UserID (Empty as of now)
```

I need to assign `UserID` in Tasks table to tasks so that all users gets tasks of even hours. I have about 5000 tasks in database and `Hours` column value range from 1 to 30.

How can it be done with SQL Server query OR LINQ?

Comment: how many hours in a day are there again?!? :P

Comment: well I think it's work hours to complete a task, not hours in a day

Comment: where is your rule book?

Comment: @Jonesy you are correct .

Comment: First, what have you tried?  Second, what database? is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: deleted my facetious answer since you changed your post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the partition problem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)), where you are trying to assign the tasks so the sum of the hours for each user is the same.

In some situations, the problem is easily solvable (for instance, if all tasks are 1 hour in length).  In other situations, the problem has no solution (for instance, if there are more users than tasks).  As a hint, when a problem has such extreme variations, it probably cannot be solved by using a SQL query.

Of course, you can *represent* the data in tables.  And, you can use a cursor over some query with complicated logic, and call this SQL.

The Wikipedia page has descriptions of several different possible algorithms.  Good luck.